# Can I set the default alignment for new objects to "view" (not "world")

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

I'm modelling a real-world object by tracing over some photos, and have multiple 3D viewports open. When I add a new object, it always defaults to "Align: World" and I have to use the F9 menu to change this to "View".

[image]

Is there a way to make the default alignment of a new object "View"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change *"New objects"* / *"align to"* in the preferences:

[image]