# Meshes are added aligned to the view

Tags: axis

[image]

Maybe I pressed by mistake a combination of keys, but now all the meshes are added aligned to view and not to axis.
How can I remedy this shortcoming?

Comment: In most cases, this is done with constraints, does your object have constraints or not? Btw does this happen in your default file or in 1 specific file?

Comment: It happens in all new files I create. I have to manually set in the panel on the low left screen each time I add an object.

Comment: You may have accidentally changed your startup file, you can reset that, see if my answer solves your problem.

Comment: Yes... the answer is here... https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/201302/can-i-set-the-default-alignment-for-new-objects-to-view-not-world

Answer (score 3):

If it's happening to each new object then it'll be the global setting for adding them, not the 'Add ...' (F9) panel.

You can change that in Preferences -> Editing -> Objects -> New Objects
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Each time you add a new object, right when the object is created, there is a little dialog on the bottom right screen that gives you more options :

[image]

Pay attention, this dialog will disappear as soon as you perform your first action to the object (like go to edit mode or transform). Check that dialog if you have `Align to View` activated :

[image]

In which case, you just have to change it back to the default which is `World`.

**EDIT**

And as @Gorgious mentioned in the comments, you can also press `F9` to pop that dialog.

**FURTHER EDITS**

As I read your comment, I think you may have accidentally overwritten your startup file, you can reset it by going to `File`>`Defaults`>`Load Factory Settings` :

[image]